# Bypassing Captcha with curl in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl, captcha

I am trying to automate the login progress on a captcha protected page. I am using Death By Captcha to translate the image into text and it seems to be working well. I am using curl to load the login page, retrieve the captcha image url, send it to DBC, get the text back and submit a POST request to the login page with the captcha text.

The problem that I'm having is that the captcha image changes when I submit the post request. Since I do not get the same behavior when reloading/or wrongly submitting the form through a browser (I get the same image over and over again), I am assuming that the problem has to do with the cookies or something else that I'm missing that relates to the session.

This is the code that I use to retrieve the data and submit the form:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
// Not sure that I need it, just make sure that the session doesn't change...   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
// It seems that PHPSESSID cookie parameter might be the parameter that keep the image the same, but it didn't work. I even read it dynamically from the cookie file but it still didn't work
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PHPSESSID=2bp3nhkp3bgftfrr1rjekg03o2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieName);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieName);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $loginUrl);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Resolve the captcha and append it to the post parameters
$captchaText = $this->resolveCaptcha($result);
$postData .= '&LoginForm%5BverifyCode%5D='.$captchaText;

// Resubmit the form with the updated form data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $loginUrl);           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //FIXED
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);           
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

When I print the end result, I can see that the captcha text was submitted successfully but that the image itself has changed...

I am also attaching a screenshot of the request params as captured with Tamper in a standard Firefox session (so someone might spot if I'm missing something).

[image: Browser request parameters]

The PHP/curl submit code is fully working for non-captcha based sites so the POST parameters submission seems to be working.

It could be that I'm missing something very basic here, any help will be much appreciated.

I also took a look at these posts but couldn't find the answer that I'm looking for.

[How CURL Login with Captcha and Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800918/how-curl-login-with-captcha-and-session)

[How to retrieve captcha and save session with PHP cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527729/how-to-retrieve-captcha-and-save-session-with-php-curl)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633282/curl-to-download-a-captcha-and-submit-it

Comment: Of course, the use of captcha is to stop you doing precisely this... if the site's author wanted you to access the page using curl, he wouldn't have implemented captcha in the first place

Comment: And for that very reason, it's up to you to workaround that problem. While a programming question, SO isn't for assisting with mischief.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is still a simple question about how to keep a session in tact while passing on cookies. In this specific case I am trying to retrieve affiliate information from multiple sources. However, if you feel uncomfortable to assist then I respect your opinion.

Answer (score 5):

you're using

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
```

in second curl_exec. shoudn't it be

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you are right. I am actually not quite sure how the submission of the POST parameters worked, but it did (I saw that the form was filled in the 2nd response). I've fixed this issue but it didn't solve the problem...